# Is there a way to __doPostBack to another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a suite of admin tools to sit on top of our existing site that will allow a user to quickly administer a number of pages from one convenient jquery ui window.

The issue I'm running into is that a lot of the functionality requires **postbacks on specific pages**, while this admin overlay can be accessed from any page. This means that in order for the functionality to work, the postback has to be sent to the correct page (or the page has to be loaded before the postback is triggered).

I've looked at [Causing a PostBack to a different page from a PopUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863550/causing-a-postback-to-a-different-page-from-a-popup) and several c# posts, but they do not appear to address the specific issue of moving to another page prior to firing the postback using javascript.

**Possible Solution:** one solution I considered is using cookies transmit information about which postback events need to fire and what parameters to use while using javascript to load the correct page. It's not a great solution, so I was wondering if anyone here could think of a better one.

Comment: Im not sure I fully understand the issue but it seems like a case for AJAX if you want to send data to different 'endpoints' from a single 'view'

Comment: The issue is that we don't have full exposure to the source code and the code behind (.cs) files. We're kind of stuck only being able to edit the front end interface and using existing postback methods.

Comment: Are you using some sort of CMS?

Comment: Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing. _doPostback is doing sync POST, but probably you can solve your problem by async POST.